# Formik not sending values from populated Autocomplete from external Source

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css, formik

Using React, Formik and Tailwind to send a form. I have some inputs that populate from Address autocomplete API(CanadaPost). Because I do not finish typing all the characters and API suggest some options for me, I just click the suggestions from the API. These options populates to the remain fields. Formik does not capture the state. It only captures what I typed. How do I I let Formik capture the remaining characters.

Fields are : address1,address2,city,state...
On adddress1, I type 8303, it will give me suggestions of addresses starting with 8303 then I will choose the correct one which then populate the correct data and pass them to input fields. The problem is Formik does not capture the states becuase the fields were not touched.

```
<Formik
initialValues = {{
address1: ""
address2: "",
city: "", 
zipCode: "",
state: "",
country: "",
}}

 onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting, resetForm }) => {
 setTimeout(() => {
alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
setSubmitting(false);
}, 2000);
resetForm();
}}
  validationSchema={validateSchema}
>

.......
</Formik>
```

I have tried
example 1

```
<label htmlFor="" className="relative block">
<span className="my-3">Address 1</span>
<input
type="text"
name="address1"
id=""
 onChange={(e, value) => {
setValidateBlur(false);
console.log(e.target.value);
setFieldValue("address1", value);
}}
 onBlur={handleBlur}
 defaultValue={values.address1}
 className="w-full py-2 pl-4 pr-3 mb-4 border rounded-md shadow-sm border-slate-300 focus:outline-none focus:border-sky-500 focus:ring-sky-500 focus:ring-1 sm:text-sm"
 />
{errors.address1 && touched.address1 && (
 <div className="w-full px-3 mb-4 text-red-900 bg-red-200 rounded-sm md:py-3 ">
 {errors.address1}
</div>
 )}
</label>
```

Example 2

```
<label htmlFor="" className="relative block">
<span className="my-3"> Address 1</span>
<input
 type="text"
name="address1"
id=""
//onChange={handleChange}
onBlur={handleBlur}
//value={values.address1}
className="w-full py-2 pl-4 pr-3 mb-4 border rounded-md shadow-sm border-slate-300 focus:outline-none focus:border-sky-500 focus:ring-sky-500 focus:ring-1 sm:text-sm"
/>
{errors.address1 && touched.address1 && (
 <div className="w-full px-3 mb-4 text-red-900 bg-red-200 rounded-sm md:py-3 ">
 {errors.address1}
</div>
)}
</label>
```

UPDATE: I have used UseRef and am able to get the current value to log on the console. The setFieldValue is not updating the initailValaues.

```
const addressField = React.useRef();

  const GetValue = () => {
    const { values, setFieldValue } = useFormikContext();

    React.useEffect(() => {
      if (addressField.current.value !== values.address1) {
        const newAddress = addressField.current;
        setFieldValue("address1", newAddress.value);
        console.log(newAddress.value);
      }
    }, [setFieldValue, values]);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

With example 2 you are on the right track - you use a controlled input component that displays the current value of `values.address1` and (presumably) updates this state variable in `handleChange` - all you need to do is to use `useEffect` hooks to react to changes of `values.address1` and populate the dependent fields.

Here is an example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/hzlx7?file=/index.js

Comment: The populate fields works fine and populates to the other fields. I do not control those. Is a mapping I did with the API. The API recognize the fields and sent the correct data in the correct fields. The problem is the values from the address1 and the populated fields does not get updated in Formik. Formik recognizes only the characters where I keydown. after I keyup and choose 1 of the options to populate the fields it does not read the values.